# How do I write Facebook apps in Java?

Tags: java, facebook, api

I have looked in vain for a good example or starting point to write a java based facebook application...  I was hoping that someone here would know of one.  As well, I hear that facebook will no longer support their java API is this true and if yes does that mean that we should no longer use java to write facebook apps??

Comment: I am not even going to bother learning the Java API for FB. I am guessing that there won't be many tutorials and books to help me with the Java development. Instead, I will learn the most popular and well supported language to write FB apps. Is it JavaScript ?

Answer (score 6):

Facebook stopped supporting the official Java API on 5 May 2008 according to their [developer wiki](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/106).

In no way does that mean you shouldn't use Java any more to write FB apps. There are several alternative Java approaches outlined on the wiki.

You might also want to check [this project](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-webapp/) out; however, it only came out a few days ago so YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

There's a community project which is intended to keep the Facebook Java API up to date, using the old official Facebook code as a starting point.

[You can find it here](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) along with a Getting Started guide and a few bits of sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I write an [example using facebook java api](http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/01/facebook-java-apieng.html)
It use FacebookXmlRestClient in order to make client request and print
all user infos
http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/01/facebook-java-apieng.html

Answer (score 1):

BatchFB provides a modern Java API that lets you easily optimize your Facebook calls down to a minimum set:

http://code.google.com/p/batchfb/

Here's the example taken from the main page of what you can effectively do in a single FB request:

```
/** You write your own Jackson user mapping for the pieces you care about */
public class User {
    long uid;
    @JsonProperty("first_name") String firstName;
    String pic_square;
    String timezone;
}

Batcher batcher = new FacebookBatcher(accessToken);

Later<User> me = batcher.graph("me", User.class);
Later<User> mark = batcher.graph("markzuckerberg", User.class);
Later<List<User>> myFriends = batcher.query(
    "SELECT uid, first_name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN" +
    "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = " + myId + ")", User.class);
Later<User> bob = batcher.queryFirst("SELECT timezone FROM user WHERE uid = " + bobsId, User.class);
PagedLater<Post> feed = batcher.paged("me/feed", Post.class);

// No calls to Facebook have been made yet.  The following get() will execute the
// whole batch as a single Facebook call.
String timezone = bob.get().timezone;

// You can just get simple values forcing immediate execution of the batch at any time.
User ivan = batcher.graph("ivan", User.class).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social). It might be limited in terms of Facebook features, but lets you also connect to Twitter, LinkedIn, TripIt, GitHub, and Gowalla.

The other side of things is that as Facebook adds features some of the old API's might break, so using a simpler pure FB api (that you can update when things don't work) might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will literally step you through everything you need to do: http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/creating-a-facebook-app-setup-and-tool-installation/

It comes in 3 parts. The other 2 are linked from there.