# Is there a way to put a heroku java app as a facebook app

Tags: java, facebook, heroku

When I create a app from facebook developer and choose to use Heroku as host they don't give me the option to put a java app, only PHP, Js, Ruby and Pyton. But when i create a app from the Heroku dev site i can create a app using java. My question is: How can i put my java app to run inside facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create your app through Facebook using those templates, to make it eventually be a Facebook app. Just write your Java Facebook app separately ([here's a good resource for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433/how-do-i-write-facebook-apps-in-java)) and the once you get that working, follow the general guide for [deploying Java apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java).